# How to get absolute value in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, absolute-value

I am trying to run pyspark script. I am trying to find % difference between two count but not able to get the proper value.
Can you please help me how to get this?

Example:

```
pre_count = 100
cur_count = 25

diff = (float((cur_count - pre_count)/pre_count)*100)
```

`diff` is giving `-100.0`

expected output: `-25`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your formula is a bit off, to calculate percentage of decrease, do:

```
|100 - 25|/100 = 0.75 = 75%
```

Which would translate to

```
pre_count = 100
cur_count = 25
diff = (abs((pre_count - cur_count )/pre_count )*100)
```

I am using python `abs()` to get the absolute difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a float you should divide floats, otherwise, you are getting a `float(-1) * 100` which is `-100` as expected.

```
pre_count = 100.0
cur_count = 25.0
```

Other than that, the difference % is as expected `-75%`.

Comment: How to get '-' sign also with percentage?

Comment: As a string? `diff_percentage = str(diff) + "%"`?